# Transferring Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard lisence key?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-activation, product-key

I'm thinking of purchasing a copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, and I plan on installing it on a machine I have. The issue is I plan to use a completely different machine with completely different hardware in the future. I do not plan to use the same copy of Windows Server on both machines, instead the new machine will replace the old one.

Is the process the same as normal Windows? Can I just reinstall server on the new machine and put my existing key in, or will the key be locked to my old hardware?

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: It should work on either but you may just have to call in to activate it depending on the type of license you buy specifically. Do you home, reach out to the seller you purchase it from with these sort of questions as well and see what they say. I've done it before with no problem but I didn't use retail license I don't think so that may make a difference. You should be able to call into MS to activate it over the phone if you have trouble though. Just be sure to keep your licensing documentation showing you purchased the license as well as any key codes.

Comment: @Walmart :/ Using an eBay seller, but if I can call into Microsoft for product activation like I would activating normal windows then I don't see a problem. Thanks for your help"

Comment: I've used eBay seller before as well and didn't have any trouble with Server 2012 R2

Comment: @Walmart Would you be able to post your comment as an answer so I can check this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I just reinstall server on the new machine and put my existing key in, or will the key be locked to my old hardware?**

It should work on either but you may just have to call in to activate it depending on the type of license you buy specifically. Do your homework, reach out to the seller you purchase it from with these sort of questions as well and see what they say.

I've done it before with no problem even with eBay sellers and **Windows Server 2012 R2** but I didn't use retail license I don't think so that may make a difference. You should be able to call into Microsoft to activate it over the phone if you have trouble though.

Just be sure to keep your licensing documentation showing you purchased the license as well as any key codes you get since as long as you have proof of what you bought and own, you'll be fine legally should Microsoft ever need to audit your environment..